# test classes with sOject type parameter

Tags: apex, unit-test

How to test the below :
Please help me test the below code..can anyone tell what parameter should be passes while calling this method in test class

```
public static String getFieldListAsCSV(sObjectType sobject_type) {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> field_map = getObjectFields(sobject_type);
        return String.join(new List<String>(field_map.keySet()), ',');
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameter would be `anysObject.sObjectType`

For eg. `Contact.sObjectType`

This method should give you a comma separated String which would contain the fields name of given sObject type.Although i'm not sure it's syntactically correct or not.

Comment: this worked, thank you. Can you please help me with below too :                      1. public static void populateFields(Sobject currObj, Map<string, object> fieldValues)                                                                                                                 2. public static string findKeyPrefix(Schema.sObjectType currSobjectType)

Comment: In first one you can pass  any sObjectReference like `Contact con`  and with that you need to pass a map.In second one the parameter given in answer has to be passed.

Comment: can you please help me with above

Comment: Util.populateFields(Account acc,Map<'abc',account>);
 Util.findKeyPrefix(Account.sObjectType);                                                             I am getting error in 1st one

Comment: You don't pass parameters like this way dear. you are only passing the type in second parameter and not the actual map.

Comment: my mistake, but trying the other way also doesn't help                                       Util.populateFields(Account.sObjectType,new Map<string, object> ('abc',Account));

Comment: Probably in place of 'abc' you need to pass name of a field of account.